# How can I add rows in a df based on a element that creates a lapply?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Im trying to create a function that makes and action using selenium, extract a text and creates an element. But, I dont know how to automate the part when the `desc` element is created for every link used in lapply, so I wonder if anyone have an idea of how to do that, and then those elements created, go to a table as final result.

This is my Code, so far:

```
## web scrapper
library(tidiverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)


rs_driver_object=rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "104.0.5112.79", verbose = FALSE, port = free_port())

RemDr=rs_driver_object$client

links=list(c("https://in.linkedin.com/company/almacenes-exito-s-a-",
"https://in.linkedin.com/company/acerias-de-colombia---acesco",
"https://www.linkedin.com/company/amt-consultores-legales",
"https://www.linkedin.com/company/constructora-amarilo-sa"))

allwebs=function(x){
RemDr$open()

RemDr$navigate("https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin")

username <- RemDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "username")
username$sendKeysToElement(list("XXX@XXXX.COM"))
password=RemDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "password")
password$sendKeysToElement(list("XXXXPASS", key="enter"))

RemDr$navigate(x)


seedesc= RemDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "line-clamp-show-more-button")$clickElement()
desc=RemDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "ember52")
desc$getElementText()

}

lapply(links, allwebs)
```